# Docker not allowing push to repo

Tags: docker, docker-registry, dockerhub

I'm following the Getting Started tutorial on the docker page, I have an image locally and have created a repo via the Docker Hub web page at https://hub.docker.com/r/banksysan/docker-whale/.

I've got a `config.json` like so:

```
{
    "auths": {
        "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
            "auth": "secret_string",
            "email": "BanksySan@googlemail.com"
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the push though I get an authentication error:

```
David@Plod MINGW64 ~
$ docker images
REPOSITORY                    TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
banksysan/docker-whale        latest              654156f34320        41 minutes ago      274.2 MB
docker-whale                  latest              654156f34320        41 minutes ago      274.2 MB
hello-world                   latest              0a6ba66e537a        3 months ago        960 B
kitematic/hello-world-nginx   latest              38502dd72c08        7 months ago        7.913 MB
docker/whalesay               latest              ded5e192a685        8 months ago        247 MB

David@Plod MINGW64 ~
$ docker push banksysan/docker-whale
The push refers to a repository [docker.io/banksysan/docker-whale] (len: 1)
654156f34320: Preparing
unauthorized: access to the requested resource is not authorized
```

What extra thing do I need to do that I'm missing?